# SVN ignore pattern for an entire project, but not global?

Tags: svn

I have a huge folder structure (80 GB in size) that used to be a Git project with lots of large binary files inside. The folders are nested quite deeply and some of them contain files to be ignored (e.g. `.mp4` files).

With Git I used to be able to just edit `.gitignore` and add a line

```
*.mp4
```

and it'd recursively ignore all MP4 files. Fine. But for complexity reasons, I thought I'd migrate this project to SVN, because Git became inefficient and slow (even just adding non-binary files caused `.git` to grow to 3 GB).

So now I'm trying to add all the existing files, but at the same time, ignore `.mp4` files wherever they appear.

I've learned that by using `svn propset svn:ignore .` on the parent directory I can only ignore specific files on that level, and that I'd have to set the property recursively on each folder where it should apply. This seems like it'd take me *hours* to do, since the files could be in lots of different places. And if I ever decided to change it to include more file types, it'd again take a lot of time.

I've also learned that I can set an OS-wide global ignore list, which would help here, but there are other projects where this list should not apply at all—maybe I want to commit an MP4 file in some project.

So, are there no other ways to make SVN ignore a file pattern within a directory tree, no matter where those files are saved?

Answer (score -1):

`svn propset` has `--recursive` option: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re23.html